# Get result from promise resolve in another async function

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to get the promise resolve result when it ends the Promise in the first function (topromise). Therefore as you'll see below I'm creating another Promise.resolve(pageData) with the value from the last then to try to get the value in my getpromise function.

This is my code:

```js
function topromise(param){
  let pageData;
  new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  resolve(param)
})

.then((value)=>{
  console.log(value)
  return "hola"
})

.then((value)=>{
  console.log(value)
  pageData= "bon jour"
  return getpromise(Promise.resolve(pageData))
})

}


topromise("hello")

function getpromise(value){
  .then(value=> console.log(value))
  //I want to get the pageData result from resolve
}
```

Comment: could you please update the snippet to something more reasonable. At the moment this would boil down to `function toPromise(){ return Promise.resolve("bon jour")  }`. To your attempt: using `pageData` like this won't work; because async. You have deal with real time. Without the promise you'll never know when `pageData` will actually contain some value.

Comment: Are you sure that your getpromise method body is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `topromise()` function is missing a `return`, and your `getpromise` function seems to begin in the middle of a method call.

It's very unclear what you're trying to do, but maybe you're going for something like this. This is working code:

```js
function topromise(param){
  let pageData;
  
  return Promise.resolve(param)
  .then((value)=>{
    console.log(value)
    return "hola"
  })
  .then((value)=>{
    console.log(value)
    pageData = "bon jour"
    return pageData;
  })
}


getpromise(topromise("hello"))

function getpromise(value){
  value
  .then(result => console.log(result))
}
```